# Matlab and simulink stateflow chart error

Tags: matlab, controller, simulink, stateflow

I have been trying to use "stateflow chart" block for hours. However, I keep getting this error:

> The current directory is c:\program files\matlab13\bin, which is reserved for MATLAB files. Please change your current directory to a writable directory preferably outside of MATLAB installation area.

What I have done: 
moved the model from bin to my E:\drive but nothing is going good.

Answer (score 2):

But did you actually change directories. For example typing in the command window:

```
cd('E:\drive');
```

You could also change your current directory by changing the current folder from the second menu bar at the top of the Matlab window. If you do it either way, you should be no longer in the Matlab installation area and the first error message should not appear. If things are still not working out, you will have to share the new error message with us.